# Error: cordova-plugin-fcm: You have installed platform ios but file 'GoogleService-Info.plist' was not found in your Cordova project root folder

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3

I am beginner ionic 3. I learn the FCM from "https://devdactic.com/ionic-firebase-angularfire/". Problem is when I write "ionic serve" every thing is ok.

But when I run in simulator error "**/node_modules/firebase/utils/promise.js

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'promise-polyfill'**". 
I run "**npm install promise-polyfill --save-exact**" command in cli in project folder Error gone.

> A new Error appear " **Error: cordova-plugin-fcm: You have installed
>   platform ios but file 'GoogleService-Info.plist' was not found in your
>   Cordova project root folder.**"

Someone Please give some suggestion to solve the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error says everything no?

> Error: cordova-plugin-fcm: You have installed platform ios but file
>   'GoogleService-Info.plist' was not found in your Cordova project root
>   folder.

You just need to add the `GoogleService-Info.plist` into your iconic project's root folder. That is it.

You can see more details here on [**this video**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IF09XbGfOu8). (*This is for Android.But the same kind of steps for the `iOS` too*)

Comment: How Can i add the GoogleService-Info.plist in ionic project's root folder?

Comment: You need to create `iOS` app on firebase console for using FCM. So at that time, it creates above file and automatically downloaded.Just copy it and put into your root.

Comment: Sorry I unable to understand what you have said. Kindly explain once more.

Comment: Hi thanks to sharing the video. Error gone but the problem is once it open in simulator it show the default flash screen and app close or stopped .

Comment: You need to debug it on the device and need to find out the latest issue.

Comment: Are you talking about real iphone device not simulator.

Comment: You can do that on either device or emulator.

Comment: I 100% sure that in simulator app is crashed. But in browser every thing is ok.

Comment: Why did it crash? You need to find out. You're developing Ionic apps not for the browser no. So you must debug it on the device.

Comment: Can You share some thing in which I can debug my code while it run in IOS simulator. Main problem simulator does not show any error. Is there any other process to find error.

Comment: Can you share some sample project about push notification which is run properly in ios device. My emailid- jitdasgupta@blueberrywebs.com. You can share in https://wetransfer.com/

Comment: Hope this helps to you: https://ionicframework.com/docs/developer-resources/developer-tips/

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have installed **Google Repository** in Android SDK Manager

[image]

I had this problem. I simply installed FCM plugin.
copy google-services.json file to root project folder. You can find this 
from your firebase project.
https://console.firebase.google.com/u/3/project/